# I would like to have two divs expand to a container div's width, but instead, I have horizontal space left over

Tags: css, html, width, liquid

I have a simple webpage with a two divs in a container div.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>

#container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#left, #right {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;

}
```

Both are side by side, don't need to expand with content because content doesn't fill the divs, but the divs need to have the same amount of padding and fill the #container div. *I wasn't clear before, but both divs need to have same padding, but different widths. One will contain a name, and the other an e-mail address, so the second is much longer.*

I can't get it so that the divs fill the width of the container div. There is a space after the #right div.

Also, everything is based on percentages, not a fixed layout, CSS only.

It seems simple, so can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You don't currently have a width set on the two floated elements. Adding one resolved everything:

```
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

#left, #right {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5% 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

#left  { background: red  }   
#right { background: blue }
​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4G7c/1/

Comment: Your answer is good, but I don't think I was clear enough. The two divs aren't supposed to have the same width as the contents aren't the same.  In mathematical terms I need (x+1) + (y+1) = (page width). X and Y are different arbitrary widths, but need to add up to a specific width.

Comment: Is there a way to make the #left div not fixed? That's the problem, this is going into a purely liquid layout.

Comment: @gohmifune The left one is fluid. Add more text to it to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>

#container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#left, #right {
  float: left;
  width:46%; padding:2%;
  height: 96%;
  line-height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without borders and padding, give the `DIV`s a `width` of `50%`. If you need borders and padding, give them `width` of `50%` and set `box-sizing` to `border-box`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes, but the most important was on `#right` removing `float: left` and then [adding `overflow: hidden`](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/2AS58/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right@sdfgsdfsdf.com</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}

#left, #right {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```